# SQL query returning only 1 row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am working on a php project where users can select a make and model of a car from a form and this will trigger the search for products that apply for that particular combination. When I run the query in SQL, and there are multiple products, I get multiple rows. but when I try to display those results using PHP I only get 1 row. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong? here's the code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM partmakes WHERE MAKE = '$_POST[make]' and MODEL ='$_POST[model]'";
$results1 = mysqli_query($cnx, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results1);


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `PARTNO`= '$row1[PARTMAKE1]' OR (`PARTNO`= 
'$row1[PARTMAKE2]' OR `PARTNO`= '$row1[PARTMAKE3]' OR `PARTNO`= '$row1[PARTMAKE4]');";

$results2 = mysqli_query($cnx, $query2);

echo "These are the products for your car:<br />";
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2)){
    extract($row2);
    echo "$row2[PARTNO]<br />";
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

---

**edit** - content from OP's file http://standtek.com.mx/test/screenshots.docx in the comments

So the user will select from a drop down the make and the model of the car. The first query looks for the make and model in the table:
[image]

Then I use the information from the PARTMAKE columns as reference for the second query

Here’s an example of the query in phpmyadmin and it shows 4 rows:
[image]

My current script displays only 1 row for some reason:
[image]

This is what I want displayed in the results: 
[image]

Comment: Instead of 2 separate queries, you could do this in a `JOIN` query. Something like - `SELECT * FROM products JOIN partmakes ON (products.PARTNO= partmakes.PARTMAKE1 OR products.PARTNO= 
partmakes.PARTMAKE2 OR products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE3 OR products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE4) WHERE partmakes.MAKE = '$_POST[make]' AND partmakes.MODEL ='$_POST[model]'`. note, make sure to sanitize your user data.

Comment: This gives me 1 row with the rest of the PARTMAKES at the end of the row. What I am looking for is to get individual rows for each PARTMAKE. Something like this:
PARTNO  DESC               PRICE
1               Something       10.50
2               other stuff          7.50

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from your 2 tables, and show your desired result.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Please take a look at the following link: [link](http://standtek.com.mx/test/screenshots.docx) There I put some screenshots of the DB and the desired results

Comment: Next time, add your notes and screenshots to your question, not as a `docx` file link in a comment. I have added the `docx` contents to your question and will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` query and you could return all the rows -

```
$query = "SELECT products.* 
          FROM products
          JOIN partmakes 
          ON (
             products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE1 
             OR 
             products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE2 
             OR 
             products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE3 
             OR
             products.PARTNO = partmakes.PARTMAKE4) 
          WHERE partmakes.MAKE = '$_POST[make]' 
          AND partmakes.MODEL ='$_POST[model]'";

$results = mysqli_query($cnx, $query);

echo "These are the products for your car:<br />";

echo "<table><tr><th>PARTNO</th><th>TITLE</th><th>PRICE</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    echo "<tr><td>{$row[PARTNO]}</td><td>{$row[TITLE]}</td><td>{$row[PRICE]}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Make sure to sanitize your `$_POST` user data.**

You can see the `JOIN` query working in sqlFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/754feb/4

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort, I appreciate it.. however it still shows 1 row :(  I know that the sqlfiddle example is showing all rows but when you try the queries in phpmyadmin it only returns 1 row. And php does not show any errors or warnings, just 1 row

Comment: There might be some issue with your data then. For example, there might be some leading or trailing white spaces, so a basic `=` will not match. You will need to look at the 3 rows that don't show up, and figure out why they are not being returned.

Comment: After some time reviewing the data the solution was to get rid of extra white spaces like you suggested. Thank you very much for your time and help!